# CORS - No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: c#, reactjs, cors, xmlhttprequest

I would like to POST data from a Font-end form (coded in REACT) to an API Server (coded in C#).

To do so, I coded the following:

***For the Front-end:***

```
const [analysis, setAnalysis] = useState(null);

const headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
    'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': '*'
};


useEffect(() => {
    axios.get(baseURL, {
        mode: 'cors',
        headers: headers,
    }).then((response) => {
        setAnalysis(response.analysis);
    });
}, []);
```

***For the Back-end:***

```
builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("MyMyAllowCredentialsPolicy",
        builder =>
        {
            builder.AllowAnyMethod()
                .AllowAnyHeader()
                .SetIsOriginAllowed(origin => true) // allow any origin
                .AllowCredentials(); // allow credentials
        }
    );
});
```

Nevertheless, I have the following issue :
[image]

I tried so many different configurations, but nothing worked.
Does someone have any idea what is the problem and how to solve it?

Thank you in advance,
Alexia

---

[Edition]

Following all the advises, I changed my code.

***The Front-end part:***

```
const headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
    };


    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get(baseURL, {
            mode: 'cors',
            headers: headers,
        }).then((response) => {
            setAnalysis(response.analysis);
        });
    }, []);
```

***The back-end :***

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

var MyAllowSpecificOrigins = "_myAllowSpecificOrigins";
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy(MyAllowSpecificOrigins,
                          builder =>
                          {
                              builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:3000/")
                                                  .AllowAnyHeader()
                                                  .AllowAnyMethod();
                          });
});

builder.Services.AddControllers();
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();


var app = builder.Build();

app.UseCors(MyAllowSpecificOrigins);

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

With this configuration I still have :

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://localhost:7067/...?id=1' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

Comment: Please understand what you're doing: using `.SetIsOriginAllowed(origin => true)` together with `.AllowCredentials()` is insecure! CORS is not to be triffled with.

Comment: Thank you for the reminder! Actually, I removed "allowcredentials" after, but still the error of CORS. Since everything is running in local host, I tried just to be sure

Comment: Start by removing all those `Access-Control-Allow-*` headers from your request. Those headers are _response_ headers, not _request_ headers. Taking this first step may improve things.

Comment: I did that, so in the font-end I just have the "Content-Type" and "mode". But I have the same issue "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource."

Comment: I'm guessing your CORS middleware comes too late, after some other middleware. If you added [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), it would be easier to tell. I'm not sure, at this stage.

Comment: I changed my post with my new updates. I hope you will be able to help me with this issue

Comment: I spotted another problem: `http://localhost:3000/` is _not_ a [Web origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Origin). Drop that trailing slash and try again. 

Comment: I solved everything! Thank you for your help !

Comment: Live long and prosper 

Comment: @Alexia Sure would be nice if you posted your solution.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue and had to do changes to the actual API code, so on your Start.cs add the following. I recommend trying it first in localhost and then deploying the changes where you actually have the API.

```
public class Startup
{
    private readonly string _MyCors = "MyCors";
    .
    .
    .
    public void ConfigureServices(...)
    {
        .
        .
        .
        //Under your services.AddControllers();
        services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy(name: _MyCors, builder =>
            {
                //for when you're running on localhost
                builder.SetIsOriginAllowed(origin => new Uri(origin).Host == "localhost") 
                .AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod();


                //builder.WithOrigins("url from where you're trying to do the requests")
            });
        });
    }
    public void Configure(.....)
    {
        //before the app.UseAuthorization & app.UseEndpoints
        app.UseCors(_MyCors);
    }
}
```